# How to separate multi-org data in Marketing Cloud? Profile attribute filter doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

TLDR - Can't seem to figure out how to get multi-org data separated by BU because the subscriber filters aren't working it seems.

We are in the process of bringing on another country into our marketing cloud org. We have a parent A and children B, C, D, etc. We've enabled multi-org because each of our country offices holds their own sales cloud license. We got connect functioning and need to keep the data separate between USA and Netherlands.

Based on what I read, we'd use the subscriber filter. We set up profile attributes and mapped it to a field in sales cloud called "Global Partner ID" that has the value "USA" or "NL" and then we were creating the filter based on that. We have the default setup as "USA".

When the sync'd data from the Netherlands org comes through I can see the data in the synchronized DE that has "NL" in it. But, it's not showing up in the org. When I go to BU A (enterprise) it shows the contact with the default value of "USA". It won't even let me change the value in contact builder. When looking further into this [here,](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_map_attribute_fields.htm&type=5) I noticed it says "Multi-org doesn’t support Web Collect or custom field and attribute mapping."

Is there any way to differentiate data between BUs not using this method? I'm kin of at a loss because salesforce and our implementation partners mentioned it could be done with multi-org enabled but maybe there's another solution I'm missing.

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by „it’s not showing up in the org” - what are you trying to achieve here? I suppose the „USA” data would be synched to child BU 1, „NL” data would be synched to child BU 2, etc, and accessed from Synched DEs in each BU. If this is what you’re after, you need to make sure you have dedicated API users for SFMC and SC for each BU, eg. „SFMC NL API user” connected to „SC NL API user” and given only access to NL BU. Also, you should block access to All Subscribers for all your users as all the data from all BUs would be eventually mixed there once you start sending emails.